# How do we make the cs cart api work after installation?

Tags: cs-cart

I installed cs cart on new server and also enabled the API user access. But the api is giving back 404 not found error. Not sure what is needed in here.

Can anyone please help!!

Comment: Please share more details. How are you using the API? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1):

please try *yoursite.com/api.php?_d=products* (e.g. in browser)

if it works, make sure that **.htaccess** root file (for apache servers) has lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/(.*)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/api/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*api/(.*)$ api.php?_d=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it might mean issue with **mod_rewrite** which is not configured or configured incorrectly on the server

p.s. if the server is on nginx, analogue configuration is needed

Answer (score -1):

1. Enable API for an administrator user

[image]

2. Folow documentation

   https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.9.x/developer_guide/api/index.html